# Backtick (`) causing problems with heroku (postgres) but not with local machine

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to put my app live on heroku but I am running into a problem that it doesn't like me using backticks (`) in my sql queries. Here is the error from the log:

```
2011-10-29T18:28:26+00:00 app[web.1]: UTER JOIN "events_users" ON "events_users"."event_id" = "events"."id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "users" ON "users"."id" = "events_users"."user_id" WHERE (`users`.id IN (2,4,17,1)) ORDER BY events.event_date DESC):
```

It works on my local machine because i am using sqlite but it is not working on heroku. So I have two questions:

1) Is there something else I can use instead of the backtick? 
2) Is postgres a sqlite alternative I should be using so that my heroku deployment matches my local machine?

Comment: 1) double quote instead of backtick, 2) Yes, if you're pushing heroku you should develop locally using postgres too so you don't get unforeseen gotchas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You should be able to use both with quotes and without quotes. Quotes are acceptable for columns, and single ticks for values. Resulting in something like:

   OUTER JOIN "events_users" ON "events_users"."event_id" = "events"."id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "users" ON "users"."id" = "events_users"."user_id" WHERE ("users"."id" IN (2,4,17,1)) ORDER BY events.event_date DESC)
2. sqlite is acceptable for local development, though if you do want exact parity you could setup postgres locally to ensure that you're creating code that runs identically.